# Django: closest possible to the project name

Tags: python, django

I am creating a reusable app that needs to know the name of the project from which it is being used. Getting the AppConfig (or just the app name) of the app with the settings module in it would be already sufficient. Other approaches are welcome as well.

*Why would I ever want this:*

- *Different projects will have portions of their data shared in the same db schema. I still need to figure out to which project does some of it belong. Project names are considered to be unique at this point, default app names are the same as the corresponding project names (`django-admin startproject` behavior).*
- *Based on the previous experience, expecting the users of my app to specify something extra in their project settings is just not reliable enough.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the project package name like this

```
import os
os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE').split('.')[0]
```